# I want to get all the data separately from firebase using Android App

Tags: android, firebase

[My Firebase database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTkdS.png)

I have an android application that stores data in firebase date wise and product wise. I have Total 4 main products that have will have multiple childs having names as current date. Check attached image.
Actually i wanted to get child count dynamically like on 4-Apr-2020 x number of applications received, and on 5-Apr-2020 y number of applications received and so on.Please check the attached image for database structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try if this code helps you

```
FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = db.getReference("NewEmailRecords").child("Islamic Financing");

ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    Log.e(dataSnapshot.getKey(),dataSnapshot.child("04-Apr-2020").getChildrenCount() + "");
    Log.e(dataSnapshot.getKey(),dataSnapshot.child("05-Apr-2020").getChildrenCount() + "");
}
```

### EDIT 1

I you need to get the children count of each and every node inside Islamic Financing. Try this ,

```
FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = db.getReference("NewEmailRecords").child("Islamic Financing");

ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
  Log.e(dataSnapshot.getKey(),dataSnapshotgetChildrenCount() + "");
  }
}
@Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
  }
});
```

---

Comment: i had used the same code snippet already, but it doesn't give me the required output. Have you seen the image, how can i get count of islamic financing node's childs date wise.

Comment: I know i can hardcode 04-Apr-2020 and get its child count, but i want to do it dynamically for reporting purposes, the code should be able to get child count each date wise for specific product

Comment: Thanks, got the required output,
04-Apr-2020/7
05-Apr-2020/3